# Create gray IplImage from gray UIImage

Tags: ios, opencv, uiimage, grayscale, iplimage

I'm a trying to create a gray IplImage from a gray scaled UIImage and Im using the method below.

```
- (IplImage *)createGrayIplImageFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image {

    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];

    CFDataRef dat = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));

    const unsigned char *buffer = CFDataGetBytePtr(dat);
    IplImage *iplimage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image.size.width, image.size.height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    for (int i=0; i<image.size.width*image.size.height; i++) {
        iplimage->imageData[i] = buffer[i];
        NSLog(@"in creategrayiplimage - %d --- %d",buffer[i], iplimage->imageData[i]);
    }
    return iplimage;
}
```

When i log the data in for loop, buffer has correct values (0-255) but iplimage->imageData has signed values even its IPL_DEPTH_8U.

e.g

in creategrayiplimage - 149 --- -107
in creategrayiplimage - 247 --- -9
in creategrayiplimage - 127 --- 127
in creategrayiplimage - 128 --- -128

This seems like a small problem but I am stuck and I wonder why i get minus values from iplimage. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A byte is a byte is a byte. The data itself doesn't know whether it's signed or unsigned -- it's all in how you interpret the data.

Change your NSLog() statement to use %u (unsigned int) instead of %d (signed int) for the format specifier and your data will be displayed unsigned.

Comment: It doesn't work with %u.
in creategrayiplimage - 126 --- 126
in creategrayiplimage - 132 --- 4294967172. How it shows buffer correctly with %d and it doesnt with iplimage? Also %u didnt help.

Comment: On the line preceding the NSLog(), you set `iplimage->imageData[i] = buffer[i]`, so you know they must be equal. According to [this page](http://tinyurl.com/27nmsdt), the type of the imageData field is `char*`, but make sure that your IplImage definition agrees with that.

Comment: Thanks! It worked when I changed it like this.
for (int i=0; i<image.size.width*image.size.height; i++) {
        iplimage->imageData[i] = (uchar) buffer[i];
        NSLog(@"in creategrayiplimage - %d --- %u",buffer[i], (uchar)iplimage->imageData[i]);
    }
    return iplimage;